# Magento 2 checkout troubleshooting steps

Tags: magento2, checkout, error

When I check the basket abandonment report under report>marketing section, I notice December has at least 5 times more basket abandonment rate if compared to the previous months.

I would like to understand if the checkout or basket page has any issue systematically.

How can I check the logs in this case? I have New Relic access too.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

To check for errors in Magento you can search for them in:

1. var/log/exception.log
2. var/log/system.log
3. var/log/debug.log

Also in your case Magento only collects abandoned carts (due to customer added to cart but not yet checked out) this is not the fault of your website